# c++ Чтобы коды повторяющийхся букв выводил через запятую

Tags: c++

c++
Часть кода:

```
string KB[] = { "любовь", "гений", "комната", "актер ", "гнев", "поступок", "адмирал" };
const int words = sizeof(KB) / sizeof(KB[0]);
string KB[] = { "любовь", "гений", "комната", "актер ", "гнев", "поступок", "адмирал" };
const int words = sizeof(KB) / sizeof(KB[0]);
//сумма кодов в слове(1-ом,2 ... 7-ом)
int _Kode[words];
string message = "нтеллект";

//количество символов в сообщении
int Marry = message.size();

for (int t = 0; t < Marry; t++){
        if ((int)message[t] < 0)
        {
            l = 127 - (int)message[t];
        }
        else
        {
            l = (int)message[t];
        }
        int p = l + _Kode[t % words];
        Massive[t] = p % 256;
        Massive1[t] = (char)Massive[t];
}

for (int i = 0; i < Marry; i++){
        cout << message[i]   << " кодируется  " << Massive1[i] <<endl;
}
```

Вывод на экран:

```
н кодируется  ‡
т кодируется  Ј
е кодируется  ¤
л кодируется  щ
л кодируется  d
е кодируется  А
к кодируется  щ
т кодируется  -
```

Вопрос:
Как мне сделать так, чтобы вывод на экран был:

```
н кодируется  ‡
т кодируется Ј,-
е кодируется  ¤,A
л кодируется щ, d
к кодируется  щ
```

Comment: использовать `std::map<char, std::vector<char>>` можно?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь мультимножеством - `multimap`. Как для этого случая сделано :)

Comment: KoVadim, Harry не могли бы вы привести пример кода? Я не очень понимаю